# Retrieving duplicate values in column SQL database

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a small database which contains a table that holds information in each row on a Movie (e.g, Movie Name, Movie Runtime, Movie Rating) and I also have a separate Genre table which contains a list of genres (Horror, Action etc).

I have an association table which links a movie to a genre (a typical row will contain the unique Id for that row, the genreId and the movieId).

I have written a query which pulls back all the genres a user has watched; however, it is removing the duplicate row values and is giving me what seems to be a distinct count.

Below is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT g.Type,
       g.Id
FROM GenreTable g
WHERE
  g.Id in (
    SELECT gma.GenreId
    FROM MovieGenreAssociationTable gma
    WHERE gma.MovieId in (
        SELECT uma.MovieSeriesId
        FROM UserMovieAssociationTable uma
        WHERE uma.UserId = '1'
      )
  );
```

This returns all of the genres a user has watched, but I'm noticing that it's not bringing back the duplicates which I know exist in the association table.

How do I get those duplicates?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that a move can have many genres, that is a movie can be both a horror and an action movie for instance?

Comment: you are correct, a movie can have many genres and a genre can obviously belong to many movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making a `JOIN` but a `SELECT` on a single table, so it will never return any duplicates unless they exist in `GenreTable`.

If you do something like `SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b IN (1,1,1,1,1)`, it will return only one row -- not five. And even if you have a complicated `WHERE` there, it's still a simple `IN` clause.

## update: quick and dirty refresher on JOINs.

I'd actually suggest you look for a SQL tutorial. **I make no claim about the completeness of this note - rather, the contrary**. [First google hit](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), [second hit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm), etc.

Say that you have two simple tables:

```
  a.id  a.a              b.id  b.b
  1     1                1     'Hello'
  2     1                2     'World'
  3     2                7     'foobar'
  4     3
```

If you run a JOIN between a and b, `ON(a.a = b.id)`, the query will select all records in `a`; *each of them* will be then joined to *all* matching records in b. This is what JOIN is for.

In this case, the second and third columns will always be equal:

```
  1     1    1   'Hello'
  2     1    1   'Hello'
  3     2    2   'World'
```

Notice that the fourth row of a is discarded because it has *no* matches, and the third row of b is never selected at all. The second row of b is selected twice, because there are two elements of a which have a match.

A `LEFT JOIN` works the same, except that if there are *no matches* for the left side of the query (i.e. table a), as it happens for the fourth row, that row is selected all the same; but the extra fields that would have come from b are replaced by NULLs. You get a further row for which the `JOIN` clause, `ON(a.a = b.id)`, is actually false:

```
    4   3   NULL   NULL
```

(And you can use this to select the rows of a that have no matches in b: just specify e.g. `WHERE b.primary_key_of_b IS NULL`).

## Your case

You should do something like:

```
SELECT
  g.Type,
  g.Id
FROM GenreTable AS g
  JOIN MovieGenreAssociationTable AS gma ON (gma.GenreId = g.Id)
  JOIN UserMovieAssociationTable AS uma ON (uma.MovieSeriesId = gma.MovieId)
WHERE uma.UserId = 1;
```

You can then `GROUP BY` e.g. Type and Id to get the `COUNT()` of movies watched for each genre.

## But...

Say that you have a GenreTable with two rows (Id=123, Type="Science Fiction" and Id=456, Type="Comedy"), a Movie table with one row (777, "Galactic Quest"), a MovieGenreAssociationTable with (123, 777) and (456, 777) because that movie is a great comedy too, and finally user 1 watched only movie 777. You would get:

```
Genre                       gma         uma        Movie
123  "Science Fiction"      123, 777    777, 1     777, "Galaxy Quest"
456  "Comedy"               456, 777    777, 1     777, "Galaxy Quest"
```

and would see that user 1 has seen *two* movies - one SciFi, one Comedy.

In this case you need to either accept the result (how many comedies did he watch? One. How many SciFis? One), or make a more complicated query for which *you must decide which is the main genre*. Otherwise you would get illogical results ("How many comedies? One. How many movies? One. Then number of non-comedies is one minus one, ie, zero? No, it is again one - wait, what?").

In this case you could add a column for this purpose in MovieGenreAssociation, a boolean column "IsMainGenre". So when you want to know how many comedies one watched, you would do as above. But when you split movies by genre, you add `AND IsMainGenre=1` and you calculate "Galaxy Quest" among SciFis, but not among comedies or parodies.

Comment: Thank you for this, could you please explain or put  a link to where i can learn about what type of join this is. I am new to sql and i have a picture showing all of the joins (inner, left, right etc). What type of join is this :)?

Comment: Could i bother you and ask how would i go about transferring this SQL code into my C# application. my application stores the UserId upon login but I am unsure how to get the GenreId and MovieId which are used in this statement. My command reader says hasRows is true but the reader contains no data and throws an error saying "Enumeration yielded no results". I am sure this is because i am not setting the genre and movie id. Please could you help?

Comment: @AaronMoriarty I am updating my answer. But the rule is to close *this* question (either accepted or deleted if not useful) and add another (better yet, first research SO and look for questions similar to the new one). As you did in this one, the new question should show what you did - query and/or C# code - and possibly what you expected, and what you got instead. You may want to look at http://sscce.org/  and http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html (and did you know there is a database Stack Exchange? ;-) )